# Where can I ask questions about mobile app in SE sites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have question about a mobile app functionality. I like to know how the app developed and how does it work. Where can i ask, such question SE sites. App is not a android, its Nokia phone application.

Question is not related to application usage,  It's about development functionality question.

Short form of question :-

How does Nokia lumia city lens app works?

Nokia lumia city lens app detect the shop, restaurant and etc by scanning the visual. but how can we detect shop or anything by scanning visual. Because we need 360 degree view to detect a location. Because we can't match visual and get the data. It's is impossible, visual will change proposanel to the distance and angle. So How does this app match the location and retrieve the information.

Comment: About a concept? I don't think there is one. Non of the sites accept market research as questions.

Comment: @Oded: Its not market research. Its about functionality of app. i ll rephrase my question

Comment: You are being too vague. What aspect of functionality? What kind of question?

Comment: @Oded: look at my edit. @S List : hope its not a telecommunication related question.

Comment: For what it's worth: OCR, and a quality GPS with directional (compass) data goes a very long way.

Comment: `It's is impossible` it exists, so it clearly isn't. Unless you live in some kind of queer world where "impossible" means something entirely different than the word we know.

Comment: @Cubic: i would like to know how that become possible. If everyone knows everything means there is know Q&A.

Comment: Look up image/pattern recognition. As you'll find in the FAQ, the site is not intended to be a replacement for own research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable site: [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Programmers SE accepts questions about software architecture, algorithms and development methodologies, which makes my question suitable.

From [its FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), allowed topics are:

> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing